# How do i programmatically check if the version of iOS installed is a beta version (Non-production)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am writing an application used by a fleet of people to do work on a day to day basis. I wanted to restrict all users to a version of iOS that is not Beta. How do i do that?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? One day it will be beta, another day it won't but you app won't have changed.

Comment: why dont you restrict access to beta build. Can be accomplished in a few diff ways rather than try to do this in code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can. I’m running the Beta 4 version of Xcode6 and the iPad simulator. I put this statement in my view

```
NSLog(@"Version %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]);
```

and got this as a result.

```
2014-07-23 12:38:10.964 AppName[47629:3783456] Version 8.0
```

At least on the simulator, there doesn’t appear to be a beta indicator.

Comment: I could hard code it that i do not want the application running if the version is 8.0.

But i'm worried that when version 8.0 becomes available then nobody will be able to use the application. I would have to update it asap.

Comment: But as others have said, why do you care? None of the iOS8 specific code can be released to the App Store until iOS8 is released to the general public, so you don’t have to worry about feature changes that will break your app. Plus, the only people running iOS8 are other developers and they know that apps may behave erratically on Beta versions.